docx_template package flutter UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: Cannot modify an unmodifiable list)
Hello guys am Trying to add image in docx file using docx_template package flutter  UnsupportedError (Unsupported operation: Cannot modify an unmodifiable list)
am gettign this error at List? value = await docx.generate(c);
Future<File> storeImageInDocx(File imageFile) async {
final appDocumentsDirectory = Platform.isAndroid
    ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
    : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String fileDirectory = Platform.isAndroid
    ? "${appDocumentsDirectory?.path.split("Android")[0]}Download/iScanConnect"
    : "${appDocumentsDirectory?.path}";
if (await Directory(fileDirectory).exists() != true) {
  Directory(fileDirectory).createSync(recursive: true);
}
String filePath =
    '$fileDirectory/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.docx';
File file = File(filePath);
var data = await rootBundle.load('assets/template.docx');
var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
var docx = await DocxTemplate.fromBytes(bytes);

var c = Content();
// c.add(TextContent("docname", "Simple docname"));
// c.add(ImageContent("image", imageFile.readAsBytesSync()));
c
  ..add(TextContent("docname", "Simple docname"))
  ..add(ImageContent("image", imageFile.readAsBytesSync()));
List<int>? value = await docx.generate(c);
if (value != null) {
  await file.writeAsBytes(value); // Write the generated .docx file to disk
  log('Docx saved to: $filePath');
  showCustomSnackBar(content: 'Docx saved to: $filePath');
  return file;
} else {
  log('Error while saving Docx');
  showCustomSnackBar(content: 'Error while saving Docx');
  return File('');
}

}

I got the same issue when trying to generate a docx with some tables and an image.
I found out the issue is caused because in "docx_entry.dart" line 29 has:
arch.files[_index] = ArchiveFile(_name, data.length, data);

while "archive.dart" line 15 has:
List<ArchiveFile> get files => UnmodifiableListView(_files);

As "files" is an "UnmodifiableListView" data, we cannot modify the content of "arch.files".
As a temporary fix to this problem, I just changed "archive.dart" line 15 to:
List<ArchiveFile> get files => _files;

You can find "archive.dart" in:
C:\Users\YOUR USER\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\archive-3.5.1\lib\src

thanks a lot let me try it hope this fix the issue
